# Jquery-validate : inputs are validated for every keystroke (only after submitting)

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

For example, if I have a number input and type "1.", it won't tell me that the number is invalid until I submit. Once submitted, every keystroke will trigger inputs validation.

Is this intended?

I understand that the plugin validates inputs upon submitting, but I'm just curious.

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/newblt123/wSbQ5/1/)**

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount" name="amount"/>


$(function(){
    $( "form" ).validate({
        rules: {
            amount: {
                required: true,
                min: 0.01
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"For example, if I have a number input and type "1.", it won't tell me that the number is invalid until I submit. Once submitted, every keystroke will trigger inputs validation.*
>
> *Is this intended?*"

Yes, it is working as intended.

Every blur as well.  And if you have radios/checkboxes, every click.

Because you wouldn't want any validation nagging the user until the user tries to submit an invalid form.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate your input fields before submitting the form. Here is a sample code for 'blur' event:

```
$(':input').live('blur', function () {
    $(this).valid();
});
```

You can check validation for some other events too.